# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuex' in '/myapp/src/store'

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am new to Vue/Vuex.
I'm trying to make a login function in my Vue.js app, and I'm getting the error below even though I have installed Vuex in my project.

```
./src/store/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuex' in '/myapp/src/store'
```

```
// package.json

"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19.2",
  "core-js": "^2.6.5",
  "vue": "^2.6.10",
  "vue-router": "^3.4.2",
  "vuex": "^3.5.1"
},
```

```
// src/store/index.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userId: "",
    userToken: ""
  },
  mutations: {
    updateUser(state, user) {
      state.userId = user.userId;
      state.userToken = user.userToken;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    auth(context, user) {
      context.commit('updateUser', user);
    }
  },
  modules: {},
})

export default store
```

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too was facing this error. These things worked for me:

1. Restart your editor. (webstorm in my case) Sometimes it doesn't recognize the newly added files/folder (node modules)
2. Delete `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and install again.
3. import Vuex from "vuex" or import Vuex from "Vuex".

Answer (score 3):

As of Jan 2021, there was a piece that I found that you had to enter `@next` in your terminal.

For example:

`npm install --save vuex@next`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

try running `npm i` maybe its not added yet

Also try this:
`import Vuex from 'Vuex'` I think the import needs to be Uppercase.

Comment: I've tried `npm i` and retried `npm install --save vuex`, `yarn add vuex` and none of them changed the situation... I have also tried `import Vuex from 'Vuex'` yet still didn't solve the problem...

Comment: I just checked the installation guide. So first it doesn't need to be uppercase sry for that one. 

For me it looks like vuex isn't installed correctly. As Your code seems to import the index.js correctly the error should be there. 

You could try to delete your `package-lock.json` as well as your `node_modules` folder and try `npm i` again. 

Also after that try to find out if the import 'vuex' referes to a export. 
e.g. in VS Code you can Ctrl + Left Click on 'vuex' and you will end up there.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it still didn't help...

Comment: It shows `vuex@3.5.1` if I go `npm ls`. I'm so confused...............

Comment: In that case maybe something is wrong with your webpack bundling. But I do have my issues with that one, too. except this everything looks fine to me.

just a small codingstyle hint you can just do

`export default new Vuex.Store..`

You don't need to define the const and export it :)

Comment: I deleted my `node_modules` folder, `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json` and re-installed Vuex and it worked... Something was wrong, I guess :S Thanks for your help and advise @Mirko t.!

Answer (score 0):

Each version of Vue uses a specific Vuex package.

- Vue 3 uses Vuex 4
- Vue 2 uses Vuex 3

Try this solution here [Failed to install Vuex in Vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71104252/5857569)