# Failed to install Vuex in Vue3

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I want to install Vuex but I get an error.

```
// error
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: vuejs-v-3@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^3.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vuex@3.6.2
npm ERR! node_modules/vuex
npm ERR!   vuex@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/hap/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hap/.npm/_logs/2021-06-24T06_46_36_463Z-debug.log
```

```
// package.json

    {
  "name": "vuejs-v-3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.20",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "vue": "^3.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: how did you install it? which command did you use?

Comment: i'm using ```npm install vuex --save```

Comment: try out `npm install vuex@next --save`

Comment: now, solved. Apparently, I'm using node v16+ . that v16 node doesn't work for vuex. to fix it i used node v14

Answer (score 13):

When using Vue3, refer to [Vuex 4 Documentation](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/) to install Vuex 4 with

`npm install vuex@next --save`

and when using Vue2, refer to [Vuex 3 Documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to install Vuex 3 with

`npm install vuex --save`

Answer (score 7):

As @Seegy said,

- Vue 3 uses Vuex 4
- Vue 2 uses Vuex 3

As of Feb 2022,

- If you are using Vue 2, use the following to install Vuex 3

  - `npm install vuex@3.4.0 --save`
- If you are using Vue 3, use the following to install Vuex 4

  - `npm install vuex --save` or `npm install vuex@next --save`

Answer (score 4):

had the same error just try
`npm install vuex@next --save`
instead of `npm install vuex --save` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: `npm install vuex@next --save --force`.

Comment: According to the `npm install` [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install) (might need to search the text for `--force` to find it though):
"The -f or --force argument will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk".
So I guess this might help in case a local copy exists but is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this before but it didn't work for me

> `npm install vuex --save`

So, this worked for me:

> ```
> npm install vuex@next --save
> ```